# Modules with $m \otimes n = n \otimes m$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Which $R$-modules $M$ have the property that the symmetry map

$$M \otimes_R M \to M \otimes_R M, ~m \otimes n \mapsto n \otimes m$$

equals the identity? In other words, when do we have $m \otimes n = n \otimes m$ for all $m,n \in M$?

Some basic observations:

1) When $M$ is locally free of rank $d$, then this holds iff $d \leq 1$.

2) When $A$ is a commutative $R$-algebra, considered as an $R$-module, then it satisfies this condition iff $R \to A$ is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings (see the [Seminaire Samuel](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/browse?id=SAC_1967-1968__2_)  for the theory of these epis).

3) These modules are closed under the formation of quotients, localizations (over the same ring) and base change: If $M$ over $R$ satisfies the condition, then the same is true for $M \otimes_R S$ over $S$ for every $R$-algebra $S$.

4) An $R$-module $M$ satisfies this condition iff every localization $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ satisfies this condition as an $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module, where $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq R$ is prime. This reduces the whole study to local rings.

5) If $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and $M$ satisfies the condition, then $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ satisfies the condition over $R/\mathfrak{m}$ (by 3). Now observation 1 implies that $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ has dimension $\leq 1$ over $R/\mathfrak{m}$, i.e. it is cyclic as an $R$-module. If $M$ was finitely generated, this would mean (by Nakayama) that $M$ is also cyclic. Thus, if $R$ is an arbitrary ring, then a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ satisfies this condition iff every localization of $M$ is cyclic. But there are interesting non-finitely generated examples, too (see 2).

I don't expect a complete classification (this is already indicated by 2)), but I wonder if there is any nice characterization or perhaps even existing literature. It is a quite special property. Also note the following reformulation: *Every* bilinear map $M \times M \to N$ is symmetric.

Comment: A related question is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/modules-m-such-that-the-automorphism-of-m-otimes-m-otimes-m-induced-by-the

and a very nice answer is given. This might be worth looking at.

Comment: I have asked the question on mathoverflow. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119689

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question has [an accepted answer at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119689/classification-of-symtrivial-modules-over-a-pid/119705#119705), and perhaps it is time to leave the Unanswered list.